# What is chronologically the last mention of redemption in the Bible?

Tags: new-testament, chronology, redemption

What is chronologically the last mention of redemption in the Bible?

Comment: Do you mean in terms of when the text was written? Or from an eschatological purpose? What's the question behind the question?

Comment: @curiousdannii - "Do you mean in terms of when the text was written?" - Yes.

Comment: Hmm, well unfortunately I think this question is a combination of the problems of verse search questions (as it depends on each answerer to say which verses they think are talking about what) and the problem of dating texts, of which their is not enough consensus.

Comment: @curiousdannii - I see. Is it possible then to come up with an array of possibly the latest mentions as opposed to an array of mentions that are definitely not the latest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The last mention of the English noun 'redemption' in the English bible (I am quoting from the KJV and using the list of words compiled by Robert Young in his Analytical Concordance) is in Hebrews 9:12.
2. The last mention of the English verb 'redeem' in the English bible is in Revelation 14:4. John the Apostle lived (and wrote) until approximately the year 100 and was (I assume without dispute) the last to write recorded scripture.
   So this might be the definitive answer to your question ... but ...
3. There are two groups of words in Greek which are translated 'redeem' and 'redemption' in English.
4. The '*agora*' group is based on the word relating to the place of public concourse and there are two main words *agora* and *agorazo* which feature in the bible.
5. The '*lutron*' group is based on the word *luo* meaning 'to dispossess' and several words are involved - *lutron, lutrosis* and *apolutrosis*.
6. So it would be more complicated if you were asking about the original manuscripts in Greek ... *and* ... *the Greek words are not consistently translated in the English bible, sometimes being translated into such words as 'purchase'.*
7. The whole subject of redemption is an important one in the bible in both the Hebrew scriptures and the Greek scriptures. The two groups of Greek words mirror two words in Hebrew *gaal* (used many times in the Book of Ruth and elsewhere) and *padah* (never used in Ruth but used otherwise).
8. The question is a little more complicated to answer than it, at first, appears.

Comment: There is plenty of disagreement over which book in the NT was written last.  See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dating_the_Bible#Table_IV:_New_Testament), and even among conservative scholars, there are many who would argue that Revelation was completed before other books in the canon.

Comment: @Nathaniel I cannot see how that can be possible, given the known facts.